# What is the canonical ring homomorphism $\varphi: R\to S^{-1}R$?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, localization

What is the canonical ring homomorphism $\varphi: R\to S^{-1}R$ ? Is it $$\varphi(r)=r\ \ ?$$

Comment: Grab the excelent Atiyah-MacDonald book "Introduction to commutative algebra". All this is explained in the first (or so) chapter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is sending every element of $R$ into the trivial fraction with denominator $1$, i.e $r \mapsto \dfrac r 1$.

Comment: Could you tel me what is the ideal generated by $\varphi(\mathfrak p)$ when $\mathfrak p$ is a prime ideal ? In my course, it's written that it's $\mathfrak p S^{-1}R$, but I don't understand why.

Comment: ...Or to $\;\frac rs\;,\;\;s\in\Bbb S\;$ in case $\;R\;$ has no unit. Anyway, *we can assume it has*.

Comment: @user352653: Instead of me explaining it here (which would be too long), take a look at ["A Course In Algebraic Number Theory"](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~r-ash/ANT.html), specifically to [Chapter 1.2. "Localization", theorem 1.2.6](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~r-ash/Ant/AntChapter1.pdf) (and the lemmata preceding it). Your question is answered there with plenty of details.

Comment: @DonAntonio I assume you mean $\frac{sr}{s}$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Of course, thanks.